# why should I set `<base href="/">` when using html5mode(true)

Tags: angularjs

Most tutorials that explain how to use `html5mode` with angularjs state that one should add `base` tag and set it to `<base href="/">`. I don't understand why this is important. Can some please explain this to me?

I'm using `ui-router`

Comment: So angular knows what URLs to decode and which to send on to the server [location documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#html5-mode)

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky, thanks, I've just tested html5mode without adding `<base>` tag (by setting `requireBase: false`) and everything works fine, so I still don't understand why I'd need to add `<base>` tag